# ListView not updating with Buttons

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Hi So I have a listview where each individual item has 4 radiobuttons. If the user clicks on the item they are brought to a new activity where they can change the radiobutton selections. But, after you press the back button to return to the listview, it is not updating the newly selected radiobutton. I have tried notifyDataSetChanged() but that doens't work. Any idea how to approach this problem?

```
public class WordListActivity extends ListActivity {
    DatabaseHandler db;

List<VocabWord> wordlist;
CustomWordListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_list);

    db=new DatabaseHandler(this);

    wordlist = db.getAllVocabWords();
     adapter = new CustomWordListAdapter(this, (new ArrayList(wordlist)));
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

adapter class:

```
public class CustomWordListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public CustomWordListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList listData){
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final DatabaseHandler db= new DatabaseHandler(parent.getContext());

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.wordView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.word_list_view_item);
holder.definitionView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.definition_list_view_item);
holder.radiogroupView=(RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioCategoryGroup_list);
holder.defaultButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.default_radiobutton_list);
holder.redButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.red_radiobutton_list);
holder.yellowButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yellow_radiobutton_list);
holder.greenButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.green_radiobutton_list);


 List<VocabWord>words1 = db.getAllVocabWords();
 switch(words1.get(position).getCategory())
    {
    case 0:
        holder.defaultButton.setChecked(true);
        break;

    case 1:
        holder.redButton.setChecked(true);
        break;

    case 2:
        holder.yellowButton.setChecked(true);
        break;


    case 3:
        holder.greenButton.setChecked(true);
        break;

    }

holder.radiogroupView.setFocusable(false);
holder.radiogroupView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);


convertView.setTag(holder);
} else{
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

}
final VocabWord word = (VocabWord)listData.get(position);
holder.wordView.setText(word.getWord());
holder.definitionView.setText(word.getDefinition());

holder.radiogroupView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedCategory) {

    switch(checkedCategory)
    {
    case R.id.default_radiobutton_word:
        word.setCategory(0);
        db.updateRow(word.getId(), 0);
        break;

    case R.id.red_radiobutton_word:
        word.setCategory(1);
        db.updateRow(word.getId(), 1);
        break;
    case R.id.yellow_radiobutton_word:
        word.setCategory(2);
        db.updateRow(word.getId(), 2);
        break;

    case R.id.green_radiobutton_word:
        word.setCategory(3);
        db.updateRow(word.getId(), 3);
        break;
    }

}
});



return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder{
TextView wordView;
TextView definitionView;
RadioGroup radiogroupView;
RadioButton defaultButton;
RadioButton redButton;
RadioButton yellowButton;
RadioButton greenButton;





}
}
```

In my "new Activity" I have a listener that takes in the newly selected radiobutton which I put in the database.

Comment: Are you getting updated columns in getAllVocabWords??

Comment: What happens when you shift your list adapter code from `onCreate()` to `onResume()` - does this fix the issue?

Comment: @Tigger I have tried that, it still doesn't work ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you press back button, the instance of convertView at the current position in getView method is not null, so the radio buttons do not update to the latest state. You should move following block code out of the code block `if (convertView == null) then { } else { }`.

```
         List<VocabWord>words1 = db.getAllVocabWords();
     switch(words1.get(position).getCategory())
        {
        case 0:
            holder.defaultButton.setChecked(true);
            break;

        case 1:
            holder.redButton.setChecked(true);
            break;

        case 2:
            holder.yellowButton.setChecked(true);
            break;


        case 3:
            holder.greenButton.setChecked(true);
            break;

        }

    holder.radiogroupView.setFocusable(false);
    holder.radiogroupView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put your `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Have you tried to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()`?